# MVVM best practice for reading back data from hardware? My View state is always one step behind my Model/hardware state

Tags: c#, mvvm, prism

I am pretty new to C# MVVM, so bear with me.

I have a piece of hardware that is storing data that has a minimum 16 ms latency between writing data and reading it back, and for safety and intuitive UI reasons, I want to display what is stored in hardware to confirm the change.

Specifically, I want to check a CheckBox, write the value of the checkbox to the hardware, then read back that value now in the hardware, and change the fill color of an Ellipse to reflect the value now in hardware.

The hardware comms are working. The problem is that my View is always one step behind my hardware. For example, when I fill the Checkbox, my hardware immediately shows '1' in the correct place, but the Ellipse indicator shows as 0. Then when I uncheck the box, the hardware shows '0' immediately, and and the View then updates to indicate '1'.

View:

```
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Ellipse Width="10"
                             Height="10"
                             Fill="{Binding ReadbackOutputB10, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToRedGreenBrushConverter}}"
                             />
                </Viewbox>
                <CheckBox Name="Bank1B0"
                    Command="{Binding OutputBitsCommand}"
                    IsChecked="{Binding OutputB10, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="0"/>
            </StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
        public ICommand OutputBitsCommand { get; private set; }
        ...

        private bool outputB10;
        public bool OutputB10
        {
            get { return outputB10; }
            set { SetProperty(ref outputB10, value); }
        }


        public IODebuggerViewModel(IRegionManager regionManager)
        {
            _IODebuggerModel = new IODebuggerModel();
            ...

            OutputBitsCommand = new DelegateCommand(() => UpdateOutputBits());
            ...

        }
        
        ...

        public void UpdateOutputBits()
        {
            _IODebuggerModel.Bank1Output = Bank1BoolsToByte();
            ReadbackOutputB10 = (_IODebuggerModel.Bank1Output & 1) == 1;
                        
        }

        private byte Bank1BoolsToByte()
        {
            return (byte)(
                (Convert.ToByte(OutputB17) << 7) | (Convert.ToByte(OutputB16) << 6) |
                (Convert.ToByte(OutputB15) << 5) | (Convert.ToByte(OutputB14) << 4) |
                (Convert.ToByte(OutputB13) << 3) | (Convert.ToByte(OutputB12) << 2) |
                (Convert.ToByte(OutputB11) << 1) | (Convert.ToByte(OutputB10) << 0));
        }
```

Model (comms to/from hardware are working)

```
        private byte bank1Output;
        public byte Bank1Output
        {
            get
            {
                bank1Output = (byte)PMCInputModel.IODebuggerStatus.Bank1OutputByte.TagValue;
                return bank1Output;
            }
            set
            {
                bank1Output = value;
                PMCOutputModel.IODebuggerStatus.Bank1OutputByte.TagValue = (sbyte)bank1Output;
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm sure this is based on some misunderstanding of how the View is updated, but I can't make it work.

I have tried added Thread.Sleep() to wait for the hardware to complete readback, but there was no change in behavior, besides a wait corresponding to the sleep time.

I have tried updating the properties bound to fields that need to change multiple times inside the function pointed to by t DelegateCommand, thinking that perhaps multiple accesses would trigger the value change in the View, since it does update on 1 state 'late', so we know the data is being successfully retrieved.

Edit - ReadbackOutputAddress is empty, which doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: What about the converter? You're sure it's working correctly? What does you log file look like when you write out the values in the setters?

Comment: @Haukinger Converter seems fine. My debug console always shows data pulled in from the CheckBox -last time-, not the value now in the box. I have the same problem with a text box bringing in numerical data to store in the hardware, so it must be some kind of order of operations problem that I don't understand.

Comment: I'd remove `private byte bank1Output;`, also I'd chose either `byte` or `sbyte`, even if it doesn't make a difference as long as your values stay below 128

Comment: @Haukinger - no change, but cleaner-looking. The bits just represent IO, so there's no numerical representation to keep track of.